# IIS not working. All websites down

Tags: iis-6

We're having a huge issue with iis6 on our Windows Server 2003.  When I came in this morning, I noticed no websites were running.  I opened IIS6 and discovered no sites were available.  Here's a snapshot of my iis:
[image: IIS Error]
<sub>(source: [functionalevaluations.com](http://functionalevaluations.com/images/iis_error.jpg))</sub>

I tried right clicking and selecting "Connect", then typing in my computer name, but it said it still wasn't able to connect.

Any idea what happened?  It was working fine last night.

Thanks

Comment: Anything in the event log?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the World Wide Web Publishing service isn't running.  If you check the Services console what is the status of that service and the IIS Administration Service?  There should also be some sort of entries in the event logs if there was a failure - there may not be any if the service was manually stopped though.